# How to make footer stay on the bottom of the page bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

This question may be a repeat!  I'd like my footer to be at the bottom of the page, but not fixed there when I scroll.  I'd like it to be like the footer on the bottom of this page [Footer Example](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/examples/blog/).  This is my footer code so far, I've been using bootstrap 4 but I can't find a class to help me with what I want.

```
<footer>
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitch"></i></a>
</footer>
```

I'm well aware of the bootstrap class

`.fixed-bottom` but like I said, I don't want the footer to stay when I scroll.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use pure CSS, like this:

```
footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #333;
  color:#fff;
}
```

Comment: @NateSedler just be careful with absolute positioning if you don't want media query hell, but if you keep it simple like this you should have no issues!

Comment: @CodeSpent I will! Thanks for the help, you are awesome!

Comment: Can confirm that it will work when using columns in your footer too. You can also use the built-in `container-fluid` class instead of `width: 100%`.

Answer (score 3):

I think you may benefit from Flexbox, unless I'm misunderstanding what you're going for. Either way I believe Flexbox is the answer, just let me know if [this works for you](https://codepen.io/codespent/pen/eKqzjX) or we can explore a bit deeper.

Here is the CodePen: https://codepen.io/codespent/pen/eKqzjX

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.main {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

footer {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  color: #ccc;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  width: 80%;
  border-top: 1px solid blue;
  justify-content: center;
}

footer i {
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">

<body>
  <div class="main">
    <h1>Hello Flex</h1>
    <p>This is Flexbox</p>

    <h1>Hello Flex</h1>
    <p>This is Flexbox</p>
  </div>
</body>
<div class="wrapper">
  <footer>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitch"></i></a>
  </footer>
</div>
```

**So what's important here?**

- We're making the *body* of our document a **Flexbox** container to allow our inner elements to be flex items.
- We're setting our `flex-direction` to `column` to flow vertically like our traditional doc flow.
- We're giving our *main* container a `flex-grow` value of 1 to fill all unoccupied space.
- We're giving our `footer` a flex-basis of auto, but also making it a flex container to make our links align horizontally effortlessly with space to work with.

Answer (score 0):

please refer to my answer here : [footer stays at bottom - stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71265828/10689189)
It is simple and will solve your issue, even if you are not using bootstrap